# NVIDIA drivers installed, but nvidia-smi not working on CentOS

Tags: centos, nvidia

I have an NVIDIA driver installed, verified by the output of `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version`:

> NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.30  Wed Jan 31 22:08:49 PST 2018
>   GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC)

However, running `nvidia-smi` gives the following error: `bash: nvidia-smi: command not found...`

More info: I am running CentOS 7, and trying to a) get nvidia-smi working and b) then install CUDA.

Comment: I suspect that nvidia-smi is missing from your $PATH even is it has been successfully installed. What is the result of (as root or sudo): `find /usr -iname nvidia-smi` ?

Comment: As you have installed and u won't see the nvidia-smi because its jus ignorning the PATH, try reinstall the driver and reboot ur machine. Thats it!!

Answer (score 2):

> Asked 3 years, 1 month ago

you stated  *I have an NVIDIA driver installed* however you did not describe how you installed it.  Be aware the nvidia driver is a kernel module and it is often *lost* after doing a `yum update` when a kernel update happens;  the nvidia kernel module is not preserved (unless you have DKMS installed) so nvidia functionality will then cease.

However that does not explain why `/usr/bin/nvidia-smi` says command not found which is another matter, but that is where `nvidia-smi` should be and `/usr/bin` should obviously be in your PATH.  Simply reinstalling nvidia via the *nvidia.run* file will fix that...

Below is **my preferred method** for doing NVIDIA install (and cuda) under RHEL/CentOS 7.x which has served me well (for about the last 3 years)

- download `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-460.67.run` from  nvidia  {get the correct one for your graphics card}  approx 150mb
- download `cuda_11.2.2_460.32.03_linux.run` from nvidia {whatever the latest version is, over 2gb}
- `su` to root; copy both to /root;  `chmod 700` on both;
- `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
- `reboot` or `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` or `init 3`
- run /root/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-460.67.run  {and observe the *building kernel module* part}
- after successful install, `/usr/bin/nvidia-smi` should be present and work;
- then do a `systemctl isolate graphical.target`  or  `init 5` and if a graphical console works then log in, and set back to `systemctl set-default graphical.target` if you prefer.
- ideally do one last reboot to validate everything is working

The CUDA install is basically the same process.

The bundled nvidia graphics driver within the cuda.run file is not always the latest.

The latest nvidia.run driver will (should) always work with whatever cuda version.

You are not required to install the bundled nvidia graphics driver within the cuda.run file, so my preference is to uncheck that when installing cuda.

Answer (score 1):

I run an HPC cluster at work and we have the cuda-driver RPM installed. It provides nvidia-smi, but its in the $INSTALL_ROOT/libs/440.64.00/bin directory. $INSTALL_ROOT might vary from system to system, so you'll have to find that first.

After I remembered we'd used an RPM named cuda-driver and not one with nvidia in the name, I found the nvidia-smi tool like this:

rpm -qa | grep -i cuda | xargs rpm -ql | grep -i nvidia-smi

Which gave me three pathnames (you can see my INSTALL_ROOT here)

/cm/local/apps/cuda-driver/libs/440.64.00/bin/nvidia-smi
/cm/local/apps/cuda-driver/libs/440.64.00/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/html/nvidia-smi.html
/cm/local/apps/cuda-driver/libs/440.64.00/share/man/man1/nvidia-smi.1.gz

And then I used rpm -qf on one of those to get the name of the RPM.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when working on a new system - if you have sudo access then:

First, try

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit OR

> sudo yum install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

depending on the system you are working with.

If that doesn't work, then try other solution.

For no sudo access machines - download drivers from the official website and then install nvidia-driver first and then cuda for the same driver version.

`nvidia-smi` is part of the `nvidia-utils` package which you need to install for corresponding driver version.

For example: for nvidia-driver 440 you will need to install `sudo apt install nvidia-utils-440`

Quick note
Use aptitude instead of apt-get

`sudo apt install aptitude -y`

`sudo aptitude install -y nvidia-driver-535 nvidia-dmks-535`